# SwiftUI: state passed to Child View not receiving updates?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview, observedobject, environmentobject

I have a `MasterView` with a List.
By clicking on an item, the `DetailView` is displayed.
I am implementing this in the standard SwiftUI way, via the `NavigationLink`.

I am passing the `detailState` to the DetailView as a parameter.

I was expecting that while the `DetailView` screen is displayed,
any change to the `detailState` would still trigger an update to the DetailView.
(showing the "loading..." screen at first, and then showing the data when it's fully loaded)

But it doesn't seem to happen.
If the `detailState` value changes, no view update is triggered.
(the "loading..." message is still shown after the data is fully loaded)

```
struct MasterView: View {
    var state : AppState
    let model : Model
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Section(header: MasterListHeader(masterState: state.masterState)) {
                    ForEach (state.masterState.itemsList, id: \.nome) { row in
                        NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(detailState: state.detailState)) {
                                MasterRow(row: row, model: model)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


struct DetailView: View {
    var detailState: DetailState
    let model : Model
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if (detailState.itemDetails.isEmpty) {
                LoadingScreen()
            } else {
                DataScreen()
            }
        }.onAppear {
            model.loadDetailItem(nome: detailState.itemName)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is where the source object is defined:

```
class AppViewModel: ObservableObject {
    let coreModel : Model = Model()
    @Published var appState : AppState = AppState()
    
    init() {
        coreModel.onChange { newState in
            self.appState = newState
        }
    }
}


@main
struct iosApp: App {
    @StateObject var vm = AppViewModel()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView(state: vm.appState, model: vm.coreModel)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var state : AppState
    let model : Model

    var body: some View {
        MasterView(state: state, model: model)
    }
}
```

What is the best design to make sure that the `DetailView` reacts to changes of the `detailState`?

Comment: how is DetailState defined and appState defined? If it’s a class you need to use  ObservedObject property to to trigger view refresh , if it’s a struct, @State is what we need. Can you share more code detail?

Comment: @TusharSharma I have just added it

Comment: I guess the best way is to retrieve the AppViewModel in both MasterView and DetailView as `@EnvironmentObject` ? However I am quite surprised that the state you pass to the child doesn't receive updates.

Comment: if AppViewModel should be accessible to every view in your code, yes you can, That way you have direct access to your model in every view.

Comment: for confirmation can you verify is your code is reaching inside and calling  line self.appState = newState, with a newValue?  I don’t see anywhere in shareCode write operation being performed on appState, apart from appViewModel.

Comment: is AppState defined as struct?

Comment: Yes, I verified that the `self.appState = newState` line is correctly called.
AppState is actually an ObjectiveC interface object (compiled from Kotlin MultiPlatform), so it's not a Swift struct. Does defining the state as struct change something?

Comment: I verified that retrieving the AppViewModel as `@EnvironmentObject` from MasterView and DetailView works perfectly.